# share buffer object between javascript and native addon that write by c++?

Tags: node.js

node version: v5.1.1
os: window7 x86

can i share buffer object between javascript and native addon that write by c++?

try belowing, but failed;

c++ addon code:

```
void setBuffer(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    char* jsBuffer = node::Buffer::Data(Local<Object>::Cast(args[0]));
    memcpy(jsBuffer, "bbbbbbbbbb", 10);
    printf("native addon output:%s\n", jsBuffer);
}
```

javascript code:

```
var native = require('nativeAddon');
var globalBuffer = new Buffer(20).fill('a');
native.setBuffer(globalBuffer); //set globalBuffer to 'bbbbbb....', using memcpy
console.log("js output:" + globalBuffer);
```

result:

native addon output: bbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

js output: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

but, globalBuffer not change, why?

Comment: Are you possibly making a new buffer with `node::Buffer::Data`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code.
I also ran it in Linux 5.1.1, and see that it works fine. That is, the changes in the native addon is reflected back in the JS code.
Unfortunately I cannot test in Windows at the moment, but will attempt soon and get back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's my fault; 
no problem in node.js, but native addon can not modify content of Buffer in render process in electron;
it's a bug for electron;